# Access difference Windows Service - User

Tags: c#, rest, windows-services, firewall, ethernet

I have the problem that I have a different behaviour of the same code when it runs as a local system service or as a user

I am trying to access some "etas" hardware which is connected with Ethernet which is purely for this hardware.

```
IPMSERVERLib.CIPManagerCom2 cip2 = new IPMSERVERLib.CIPManagerCom2();
cip2.CreateIPManager(0, 1);
IPMSERVERLib.ICGetConnectedSystems cs2;
cs2 = cip2.getNewConnectedSystemsObject();
cs2.update();
Console.WriteLine(cs2.getNoOfConnectedSystems()));
```

When i run the code as a user I get always on all computers the correct number of two (two systems)

When i run the code as a windows service (Web-service) i get on 20% of the systems the wrong number.

I don't get an error so the code always runs through.
The local system should have more access rights then the user. So i am completely struct why this is not working.
The windows version, software version of the products are always the same.

What is really the different from accessing from a windows web service then from a user?

Comment: What is a “windows web service”?

Comment: sorry i meant i have a windows service written which acts as a REST service. So the code above will be called everytime when someone wants to get infomations about connected hardware